# power arduino nano with usb external battery charger

Tags: arduino, power, batteries, usb

I want to power my arduino nano with my phone external battery charger.
The problem is, when I connect them through a USB cable and turn on the battery charger, it works for serval seconds and then the battery charger turn off.
I was surprised because I didn't think that the battery charger is smart enough to identify the device it connected to. Any ideas how I can bypass it?

Comment: did you tested voltage and current in whole time from start to shut down charger ? maybe your charger have internal defence from overcharging your battary!? a test for charged battery, and shutdowns when "feel" that connected device is charged !? and to bypass them, bout